# should Variance of EmpiricalDistribution include Bessel correction? (it doesn't)

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I was rather surprised by this:

```
testData = RandomChoice[{0, 1}, 100];
testEdist = EmpiricalDistribution[testData];
Variance[testEdist] == Variance[testData]   (* False *)
Variance[testEdist] == Variance[testData]*99/100   (* True *)
```

I'd like to hear why this behavior is the right decision for an empirical distribution.  (I'm aware I can just adjust or use the second `CentralMoment`; that's not my question.)

Comment: "The population rather than the sample variance is used for empirical distributions..." right in the docs. For whatever reason WRI chose that. As to why it is/is not the right decision? Better perhaps to ask on crossvalidated.se...

Comment: Which docs?  I'm looking at https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Variance.html and not seeing that sentence.  Thanks.

Comment: [Properties and relations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EmpiricalDistribution.html)

Comment: Not sure where you're looking, but the word "population" is nowhere on that page.  (I also did a search on the bundled help; version 10.2.)  Sorry if I'm overlooking it someplace obvious, but it's not where you said.

Comment: The decision was made in order to maintain a consistency with the rest of the distributions framework. If you want the sample variance it seems easy enough to obtain.

Comment: Also, since empirical distribution works with weights and censored data the concept of sample size isn't always clear.

Comment: @AndyRoss Your last comment is what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation, under *Properties and relations*:
[image]

Comment: Ah, you're on a completely different page.  Thanks.